# Can partitioning improve performance if I search on columns other than CustomerNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am reading a partitioning tutorial of SQL Server on:

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/partitioning.htm

Here the author splits the table and stores them into 4 filegroups based on the `CustomerNumber` column.

What I want to know is, if I search on first name or last name:

```
Select * From tableName where FirstName Like '%Jack%'
```

would this query run faster if I partition? Will SQL Server issue 4 queries on separate filegroups and then merge the final results?

**Edit:**

While this wasn't my original question but Raj and TimTom said it would result in table scan, but the query execution plan shows something else what I said. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: "...Like '%Jack%'" is a bad query, partition or otherwise. It will cause a table scan

Comment: @Raj: So which is a good query to search for records containing Jack? Also you are wrong table scan. With indexing on *FirstName*, this would cause a index scan not table scan. Secondly, my question is about partitioning not indexing or table scan. Simply put, will partitioning be beneficial or not in this case.

Comment: Using full text search. THat is about the only one. And no, %Jack% is a table scan, always, even with index - the first "%" means an index can not be used. Partitioning will not help. What helps is proper programming. If there are no spaces before the "Jack" (trimming) then the query can be written as "LIKE 'Jack'" or "LIKE 'Jack%'" and then an index WILL be used.

Comment: In my experience the first %-sign will make any index useless and will result in a table scan. I know the question is not about index, hence commented, not answered.

Comment: Well, one of the benefits of partitioning can be that SQL Server knows in which partition to go search for data, e.g. if you've partitioned by year and you want data from 2010, it will need to check that partition only. This reduces the scope of the search and thus speeds things up. But if your data is partitioned by one criteria (like year, or customer number) and you search for something else - that doesn't really help.... SQL Server will still need to search the whole range of data....

Comment: @marc_s: You understood and answered my question perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @TimTom: Please see the screenshot I posted above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Clustered index is the physical order of the table. Clustered index scan is the same as table scan. Try creating a non-clustered index on fname column and see if it gets used.

Comment: @Raj: No, it doesn't. It still results in clustered index scan. Further it is always clustered index even though I use  where *city = 'abc'*. Index created on city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can partitioning improve performance...

No. Partitioning is never about improving performance, is about data storage management and/or switch-in/switch-out ETL processing. IO parallelism can be achieved with multiple files in a single filegroup w/o the (severe!) drawbacks of partitioning. If you want a *good* article about partitioning I recommend Kendra Little [How To Decide if You Should Use Table Partitioning](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/).

As for your question: `LIKE '%text%'` can only be answered efficiently using a fulltext search.

Comment: +1. I've seen only outlier cases where partitioning had a slight effect, and even then, it was slight.  These, of course, were offset by the maintenance time required for managing partitioning (which many forget).  I tested some cases with row and page compression that worked much better than partitioning.  As you wrote, data storage is why partitioning is a consideration, especially if we know that the data will grow rapidly, and we should be aware that extra costs for management of it will be required.